# python sampling using readline gives memory error

Tags: python, memory, readline, sampling

I tried to sample a data file with over 260 million lines, creating an evenly distributed sample with a fixed size of 1000 samples.

What I did was the following:

```
import random

file = "input.txt"
output = open("output.txt", "w+", encoding = "utf-8")

samples = random.sample(range(1, 264000000), 1000)
samples.sort(reverse=False)

with open(file, encoding = "utf-8") as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    count = 0
    while line:
        if count in samples:
            output.write(line)
            samples.remove(count)
        count += 1
        line = fp.readline()
```

This code resulted in a memory error, with no further description. How come this code can give a memory error?

As far as I know it should read my file line by line. The file is 28.4GB, so it can't be read as a whole, which is why I resorted to the readline() approach. How could I fix this, so that the whole file can be processed, regardless of its size?\

EDIT:
The latest attempts throw this error, which is practically identical to each of the prior error messages I have gotten so far

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a772dad1ea5a> in <module>()
     12 with open(file, encoding = "utf-8") as fp:
     13     count = 0
---> 14     for line in fp:
     15         if count in samples:
     16             output.write(line)

~\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

MemoryError:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I finally solved the problem: all code here works properly,
the range issue is indeed only present in versions prior to 3.0,
where it should be xrange(1, 264000000).

The input file was constructed in a different code file,
where it was written as follows:

```
with open(file, encoding = "utf-8", errors = 'ignore') as fp:  
line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        input_line = line.split(sep="\t")
        output.write(input_line[1] + "," + input_line[2])
        line = fp.readline()
```

The problem here is that this code does not construct a file with lines, but just adds information to the first line. Therefore, the whole file was read as one big line, instead of as a file with a lot of lines to iterate over.

Thanks a lot for your help and my sincere apologies for the fact that the problem was situated elsewhere in my project.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this line causes a huge memory spike:

```
samples = random.sample(range(1, 264000000), 1000)
```

My guess is that this call forces python to create all 264M ints in that range before it can do the sampling. Try this code instead for sampling in the same range without replacement:

```
from random import randint

file = "input.txt"
output = open("output.txt", "w+", encoding = "utf-8")

samples = set()
while len(samples) < 1000:
    random_num = randint(0, 264000000)
    if random_num not in samples:
        samples.add(random_num)

with open(file, encoding = "utf-8") as fp:
    count = 0
    for line in fp:
        if count in samples:
            output.write(line)
            samples.remove(count)
        count += 1

        if not samples: break
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!
Unfortunately, this approach resulted in the same memory error...

Comment: Ah, I think I found the error. I ran just this line in my interpreter and the memory usage spiked `samples = random.sample(range(1, 264000000), 1000)`. Try my edited code instead. I also updated my answer with a reason as to why this line might cause a memory error.

Comment: Actually, are you running python2 or python3?

Comment: I use Python 3. Still, the process starts using over 6GB of RAM (out of the 8 that I have), then it starts to slow down, until it throws another memory error...

Comment: Ok, in python3 `samples = random.sample(range(1, 264000000), 1000)` should be fine anyway. That runs quickly on my machine. Was original comment regarded python2 which uses more naive `range` function. I'm going to access a larger machine today to run some tests, I'll respond again later.

Comment: It may be helpful to know at what line in your program you get the error? Could you edit your response to include the full error output?

Comment: What type of system are you on (Windows?) Also looks like you're running iPython Notebooks, correct?